# Finding the web page which is calling a SP

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've got a stored procedure which is called from some piece of code. But I cannot understand exactly which one.

Is it possible to ask to the Database or the network to monitor that SP to find who is the caller? How?

The database is SQL Server (one of the latest versions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the correct answer, but when I connect via my local computer and run this, I can get my IP address.  I do not believe SQL server would be able to identify what web page is making the call, but rather knowing that "I have a connection from X", as such, you would need to add the "Application Name" to the connection string.  This can be pulled out of the activity monitor.

[Use Application Name in SQL Server](http://www.connectionstrings.com/use-application-name-sql-server/)

```
SELECT session_id, client_net_address, hostname, program_name
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_connections c 
INNER JOIN
    sys.sysprocesses s on 
    c.session_id = s.spid
WHERE 
    session_id = @@spid
```

Comment: Ok, but at the end of all there should be a way to track who is making the connection. Since someone knows that.. Let assume that the DB knows only an ip address and a port. The network guy can understand the caller program ie. IIS.exe, from that I should be able to check IIS log and see.

Comment: You know, I never thought of this til now.. (duh moment?)  Have you considered adding "Application Name" to your connection string to help you identify between websites?  You can pull this out of sql server too.